# Web API POST method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-web-api

**Route Config**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

**POST-method**

```
[HttpPost]
public Probabilities Post(string word, string userId) {
    Request request = new Request();
    request.Identify(word, userId);
    Probabilities probabilities = probabilitiesFactory.GetBy(request.ProbabilitiesId, "Id");
    return probabilities;
}
```

Im trying to post some data, shown on the screenshot

[image: Postman]

And im getting an error

`"No action was found on the controller 'Identification' that matches the request."`

What is happening? How to post 2 simple strings and get the result

Comment: What is the exact name of your controller? The class that contain your action.

Comment: @codenotfound its name is `IdentificationController`

Comment: What the Headers tab contains in your postman UI ?
It should work. MAybe you need to change the "Text" tab to "Json" :)

Answer (score 1):

While not mandatory, you should follow good practice and encapsulate the payload into a model.

```
public class MyModel {
    public sting word { get; set; }
    public sting userId { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use the `FromBody` parameter attribute to bind the model to the data sent.

Finally addressing the resource not found issue, ensure that the controller is following the proper convention given that the OP is configured with convention-based routing.

```
public class IdentificationController : ApiController {

    [HttpPost]
    public Probabilities Post([FromBody] MyModel model) {
        string word = model.word;
        string userId = model.userId;
        Request request = new Request();
        request.Identify(word, userId);
        Probabilities probabilities = probabilitiesFactory.GetBy(request.ProbabilitiesId, "Id");
        return probabilities;
    }
}
```

[Reference: Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

[Reference: Routing in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different solutions for this problem. 
**First:**
Send `word` and `userId` as `QueryStrings`.. here's an example:

```
http://localhost/api/identification?word=hey&&userId=12
```

this will work in your case so you won't need to change anything in the code.

**And Finally my favorite solution:**
Create a model class like that:

```
public class IdentificationModel{
    public string word { get; set; }
    public string userId { get; set; }
}
```

then require it as a parameter object in you method like that:

```
[HttpPost]
public Probabilities Post(IdentificationModel requestModel) {
    Request request = new Request();
    request.Identify(requestModel.word, requestModel.userId);
    Probabilities probabilities = probabilitiesFactory.GetBy(request.ProbabilitiesId, "Id");
    return probabilities;
}
```

The last one does not require adding `[FromBody]` attribute since any class object is an api method will automatically be waited as a Request Body Object.

Comment: I found that the variables on the model class only got set if they had a public get and set method.

Comment: @AdamR.Grey Yeah I guess you were right I forgot it, I edited my answer. Thank you.